# Finding a power series for $\tanh^{-1}{z}$ and using it to sum a series

Tags: complex-analysis

I am ok with finding a power series for $\tanh^{-1}{z}$ since I can just see that since $\tanh iz = i\tan z$, then $\tanh^{-1}z = \frac1i \tan^{-1}{iz}$ and use the power series for $\tan$ to get:

$$\tanh^{-1}{z} = \sum^\infty_{k=0} \frac{z^{2k+1}}{2k+1}$$

But then I am asked to deduce that:

$$1- \frac15 + \frac19 - \frac1{13} + \ldots = \frac{\pi + 2 \ln(1+\sqrt{2})}{4 \sqrt 2}$$

Looking at this sum, it looks like it's the power series for something involving $\tanh^{-1} 1$ and $\tan^{-1} 1$. But surely $\tanh^{-1} 1$ won't be defined?

I'm stumped, there's probably something I'm not seeing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding $\tanh^{-1} e^{i\pi/4}$ gives:

$$\sum^\infty_{k=0} \frac{e^{i\pi(2k+1)/4}}{2k+1} = e^{i\pi/4}\left(1 + \frac{i}3 - \frac15 - \frac{i}7 + \frac19 + \ldots\right)$$

So we can simply multiply by $e^{-i\pi/4}$, take the real part, and after simplifying, we get the result.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use the expansion $\dfrac {\tan^{-1}(z)+\tanh^{-1}(z)}{2\,z}\;$ with $z$ such that $z^4=-1$
($\,\tanh^{-1}(z)=\dfrac{1}{2}\ln \left(\dfrac{1+z}{1-z} \right)$ may help too!).